# Image Not Rendering in ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, ejs, multer

**I have a simple app which gets heading, description and image from the user `multer`** handle the image uploading part and I get the images in static folder called public and its sub folder uploads. Then it is toed in the database. I find it in database and try to render the image but image is not rendering. Although it is present in uploads folder but it is not rendering.
Here is My code.

```js
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const app = express();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const multer = require("multer");
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");

//APP use
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static(__dirname+"./public/"));

//Multer Setup
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: "./public/uploads/",
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, file.fieldname + '_' + Date.now()+path.extname(file.originalname));
    }
});
const upload = multer({ storage: storage }).single("img");




//Mongoose Setup
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/project-1', {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true}).then(console.log("Successfully connected to the server"));

//Routes
app.get("/", (req, res)=>{
    BlogModel.find({}, function(err, foundItem){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }else{
            console.log(foundItem);
            res.render("home", {foundItem : foundItem});
        }
    })
    
});
app.get("/creat", (req, res)=>{
    res.render("creat");
});
app.post("/creat", upload ,(req, res)=>{
    const data = new BlogModel({
        heading: req.body.name,
        desc: req.body.desc,
        img: req.file.filename
    });
    data.save((err)=>{
        if(!err){
            res.redirect("/");
        }else{
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
    console.log("Successfully Submited The Form");
});


//Database Schema
const Blogschema = new mongoose.Schema({
    heading: String,
    desc: String,
    img: String
});

//Database Model
const BlogModel = new mongoose.model("Image", Blogschema);







//Listen On Port 3000
app.listen(3000, ()=>{
    console.log("Listening on port 3000");
});
```

```html
<%- include('partials/header'); -%>



<% foundItem.forEach(function(item){ %>
        
    <h1><%= item.heading %></h1>
    <p><%=item.desc%></p>
    <img src="./uploads/<%=item.img%>" alt="image">

<%})%>



<%- include('partials/footer'); -%>
```

[Here it is stored in the public Folder inside Uploads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GABrI.png) 
[Here is the error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDqMF.png)
Sorry if the code is to long.

Comment: Did you try  <img src="/uploads/<%=item.img%>" alt="image"> (starting the path with '/')

Comment: yeah I tried but it didn't work. Any other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding 'public' for static folder name

```
app.use(express.static("public"));
```

Or if you want to use __dirname,

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
```

Comment: Thanks, I just want to ask the way I created the static public folder was wrong???

Comment: No, in your code you added as "./public/" for folder name. That is incorrect. Because when you concatenate it with __dirname, it will return as "someFile/./public/"